# Convert Particle System to Object With Unique Faces

Tags: mesh, particles, linked-data

I've been trying to find info around converting hair particles into a mesh, but with "unique" faces. I'm able to convert the particles into the mesh, which creates a number of linked objects under the Outliner window.

Once complete, each object (object.001, object.002 etc) is linked in so much that selecting a face on one selects that same face on all the others. I can't work out how to unlink them so that each face is its own unique face, and not linked to the rest. When trying to unlink it just removes it from the scene.

I've so far tried a few applications, (make instances real) etc, but I'm not sure how to combine it all into single object.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by going to *Object > Relations > Make Single User*.